# Simple Question about Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data

I using the project named coredatabooks from apple developer examples.

```
#import 

@interface Book : NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *active;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *author;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *copyright;

@end
```

I need to use a bool object, but I don't know how to implement it in my class.. I'm using right now NSNumber, using an integer (0, 1) but is not a Bool... maybe it will be more correct to use this ...

@property (nonatomic, retain) bool active;

but is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use an NSNumber, but [pack it from a bool](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNumber/numberWithBool:):

```
[NSNumber numberWithBool: myBool];
```

and [unpack it to a bool](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/boolValue):

```
[myNSNumber boolValue];
```